# Probability of a random point in a disk?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

Let a point be picked at random in the disk of radius $1$. Find the probability that it lies in the angular sector from 0 to $\pi$/$4$ radians.

I just started teaching myself probabilty and came to this question. I found this in an Intro to Probability text and was wondering how would we solve this type of problem.

If I had to guess, my answer would be $1/8$ or $\pi$/$8$.

Here is the work:

$\pi$/4 $*$ $1/2$ since the disk is a radius of $1$.

Is this correct? If so, can you please show if there another way that I can solve this problem.

Comment: Is your answer $1/8$ or $\pi/8$? It can't be both.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is indeed $1/8$, and here's a justification:

We're choosing a point on the disk at random, which means here that each point on the disk is equally likely to be chosen. It follows that the probability of choosing a given region is proportional to its area.

The sector from $0$ to $\pi/4$ takes up $\frac18$ of the area of the circle.  Since any $\frac18$ of the circle has the same chance of being chosen, the probability that our sector is selected is $1/8$, since we are choosing $1$ eighth of the disk out of $8$ equally likely possibilities.

Comment: The probability from choosing a point is 0 and therefore all points have the same probability that they are chosen but from this does not follow that the probability of choosing a region is proportional its area. At least is is not evident that this is the only probability measure that can be defined on a disk with this property $p(x)=0, \forall x$

Comment: @miracle173 my saying that "each point on the disk is equally likely to be chosen" is my way of saying that the probability distribution function on the disk is uniform. While it isn't very meaningful to talk about the probability of a particular point out of the disk (which is of course zero), it makes sense to compare the likelihood of selecting one point over another. In this case, we find that any two points are "equally likely".

Comment: There is also no meaning in speaking about likelihood of selecting a point or comparing the likelihood of selecting two different points when this likelihood is 0. I think uniform distribution is defined by the fact that the probability or likelyhood of a random selected point to be from a given area is proportional to the size of this area. There is no way to get from the "likelihood of selecting a point" to the likelihood of selecting a point from an area.

Comment: @miracle173 It is perfectly acceptable to define the probability over "regions" and "lengths" using a [probability density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) that is defined at a point. A uniform distribution is one in which the probability density at each point in the domain is equal. The probability density is not the probability of selecting a point from an area (which is, as we've agreed, zero) but can be viewed as  a relative measurement of the likelihood of picking a given point.

Answer (score 4):

The desired probability is the ratio of the area of this angular sector to the area of the entire disk. Since area is proportional to the size of the central angle, it follows that the desired probability is:
$$
\dfrac{\pi/4}{2\pi} = \dfrac{1/4}{2} = \dfrac{1}{8}
$$

Answer (score 3):

By symmetry, there is nothing to choose between the eight octants; so the probability is equal for each of them: one eighth.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is fine and it is independent of the radius:
$$
\int_{0}^{a}{2r \over a^{2}}\,{\rm d}r
\int_{o}^{\pi/4}\,{{\rm d}\theta \over 2\pi}
=
{1 \over 8}
$$

Answer (score 0):

there is a chance of 1 to put it anywhere on the disk. (ian assumption i make but i guess it is a good one)
the area of the disk is ?1
the area that counts as a win is ?2

the area of ?2 / ? 1 is your probability.

Probabilites are always relative and are always between 0 and 1 (including both) so if you get ananswer that is bigger than one, or can change the question so the answer gets bigger than 1 something is wrong